# The Proper way to configue an "Assigned To" notification?

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow

I can seem to wrap my mind around what is probably a simple procedure and I am hoping someone here can provide some guidance.

Here is the scenario:  I have a SP2010 list where the items contain a field for "Assigned To".  My objective is to have an email notification sent from SharePoint to the user who is set in the "assigned to" field.  This I have managed, however with my current configuration the user receives an email EVERY time the item is modified and saved as long as his username remains in the Assigned to field.

Here is my workflow logic on the associated list in SharePoint designer 2010:

> ---
>
> Step 1
>
> `Wait for Assigned To to be not empty then Email Current Item:Assigned To`
>
> ---

The workflow is set to "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed".

What I need to happen is for the user to be notified the FIRST (and only the first) time the assigned to field has his or her name in it...not every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Store the initial value of `Current Item:Assigned To` in a workflow variable (say, `Workflow Variable:CurrentAssignee`) and then `Wait for Current Item:Assigned To to not equal Workflow Variable:CurrentAssignee`. Then send the email.

Comment: That sounds simple enough.  Do I create the variable using the "Local Variables" option (in the ribbon) somehow?

Comment: I usually type "set w" and then choose from two options.